# SCTP message is not getting initiated

Tags: sctp

Trying to initiate the SCTP association, but no message is getting initiated. Checked in the redhat linux machine, couldn't see sctp.

checksctp
checksctp: Protocol not supported

lsmod | grep sctp

lksctp-tools-1.0.17-2.el7.x86_64 package is installed in server. Please help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load `sctp` kernel module

```
sudo modprobe sctp
```